# How to show a widget when the marker is clicked on in gmap flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to show a widget with the latlong info and a button when the marker is placed on the map.or clicked on marker.

**this is my code to handle the markers**

```
  Future<void> addMarker(
      LatLng mLatLng, String mTitle, String mDescription) async {
    final Uint8List markerIcon =
        await getBytesFromAsset('assets/images/icons/pin.png', 100);
    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();
      _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId:
            MarkerId((mTitle + "_" + _markers.length.toString()).toString()),
        position: mLatLng,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: mTitle,
          snippet: mDescription,
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(
            markerIcon), //BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ));
    });
  }

  Future<void> _handleTap(LatLng tappedPoint) async {
    print(tappedPoint);
    final words = await api
        .convertTo3wa(Coordinates(tappedPoint.latitude, tappedPoint.longitude))
        .language('en')
        .execute();
    print(words.data()!.words);
    LatLng mLatLng = tappedPoint;
    String mTitle = '///${words.data()!.words}';
    String mDescription =
        'Coordinates: ${words.data()!.coordinates.lat}, ${words.data()!.coordinates.lng},\nNearest Place: ${words.data()!.nearestPlace}';

    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();
      if (words.isSuccessful()) {
        addMarker(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription);
        getPillInfowindow(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription);
        //_customInfoWindowController.hideInfoWindow!();
      } else {
        print(words.error());
      }
    });
  }
```

**and the widget i want shown when marker is clicked on is this**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mymapp/screens/home_page.dart';

    Widget getPillInfowindow(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription) {
      return Positioned(
        bottom: 100, right: 0, left: 0,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            height: 70,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 20,
                      offset: Offset.zero,
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5))
                ]),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    child: ClipOval(
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/icons/pin2.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover))),
                // first widget
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('title:${mTitle}', //${mTitle}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors
                                    .green)), //currentlySelectedPin.labelColor)),
                        Text(
                            'Latitude, Longitude: ${mLatLng}', 
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey)),
                        Text(
                            'Desc: ${mDescription}', // 
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey))
                      ], // end of Column Widgets
                    ), // end of Column
                  ),
                ), // second widget
    
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ); // end of Container
    }
```

but somehow this doesn't work the way I want it to. What's wrong here?

Sorry if there's mistakes here, I'm a beginner in flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Future<void> _handleTap(LatLng tappedPoint) async {
  // Your existing code to get the marker information
  // ...
  
  setState(() {
    _markers.clear();
    if (words.isSuccessful()) {
      addMarker(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription);
      _pillInfoWindow = getPillInfowindow(mLatLng, mTitle, mDescription); // Update the _pillInfoWindow variable with the new marker information
    } else {
      print(words.error());
    }
  });
}
```

then

```
Stack(
  children: [
    GoogleMap(
      // ... your existing GoogleMap widget code ...
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _mapController = controller;
      },
      onTap: _handleTap,
      markers: _markers,
    ),
    if (_pillInfoWindow != null) _pillInfoWindow!, // Add the _pillInfoWindow widget to the Stack
  ],
)
```